# How to check if my wireless connection uses AES or TKIP from a terminal?

Tags: wifi, encryption

I have a wireless router that has settings to use AES, TKIP or AES+TKIP encryption for wireless connections.

My Linux-based device does not like AES (it drops out from time to time), my girlfriend's MacBook Pro does not like TKIP (refuses to connect at all), so it seems I'm stuck with the AES+TKIP setting.

Is there any command I can use to check that my Linux device is using TKIP?
Or even better, one to force it to use TKIP?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the tool you are looking for is `iwpriv`.

```
iwpriv wlan0 set EncrypType=TKIP
```

Assuming that your wireless card is wlan0.

Comment: That just gives me `wlan0      no private ioctls.` (My interface _is_ `wlan0`.)

Comment: Did you run that as a super? (either as root or via sudo?)

Comment: Yes. And iwconfig confirms that `wlan0` is the active interface.

Comment: You may need to disable network manager and/or ifdown the card before iwpriv will work

Comment: Network manager is not installed, but I'll try the latter.

Answer (score 1):

With the new [Krack attack](https://www.krackattacks.com/), do not use TKIP:

> If the victim uses either the WPA-TKIP or GCMP encryption protocol, instead of AES-CCMP, the impact is especially catastrophic. **Against these encryption protocols, nonce reuse enables an adversary to not only decrypt, but also to forge and inject packets.**